# Using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16 to reverse proxy Tomcat 7: webapp not found

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, reverse-proxy, apache2.4

I am using the instructions on [this page](http://chirag.bodar.in/configure-apache-httpd-24-with-tomcat-7x-on-ubuntu-1204-1304-and-1404) to use Apache, using SSL, in front of a Tomcat 7 instance, that is *not* using SSL, and which has one webapp deployed.

I have followed all of the instructions and am able to navigate to:

```
http://localhost
https://localhost
http://localhost/my-webapp
```

The only thing that is *not* working is

```
https://localhost/my-webapp
```

It returns a 404 Not found error.

I have posted below the pertinent parts of my conf files.

Apache 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ProxyPass /my-webapp ajp://localhost:8009/my-webapp
  ProxyPassReverse /my-webapp ajp://localhost:8009/my-webapp
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache default-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ...
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
  ...
  <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    ...
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I have all the mods enabled, and both ssl and proxy seem to be working.
When I navigate to

```
  http://localhost/my-webapp
```

without https, the proxy works fine. And when I navigate to

```
  https://localhost
```

it also works; it returns the static Apache page. (It complains about the self-signed certificates not being secure but otherwise, it works ...)

Shouldn't

```
  https://localhost/my-webapp
```

also work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the proxy inside virtualhots_443

```
  ProxyPass /my-webapp ajp://localhost:8009/my-webapp
ProxyPassReverse /my-webapp ajp://localhost:8009/my-webapp
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been using Apache 2 on CentOS and on that OS I only had one conf file, ssl.conf. On Ubuntu there are 2 conf files, one for "normal" mode, port 80 (000-default.conf), and one for ssl (default-ssl.conf). I didn't even realize that at the top of the file it clearly says which port you are configuring, I just thought all the stuff in 000-default.conf would be applied everywhere, while the stuff in default-ssl.conf would be only applied to https. As you can tell, I don't have much experience configuring Apache servers ... Anyway, thanks again!